# Calculate percentage change between two values

Tags: google-sheets

I've searched a sea of results but haven't found a solid answer to my specific question. Hopefully someone can help me out. I'm using cells C2,D2, and E2. Here's what I'm after. In cell E2, if C2 is greater than D2, E2 must display C2-D2/C2x-100, or if C2 is less than D2, E2 must display C2-D2/C2x100. The formula for those interested is stocks, if the current price of a stock is less than the opening price of the stock, display the percentage decrease (negative number) and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

`=iferror( (C2 - D2) / D2 )`

With the current price `101` and opening price `100` this will give `1.00%`.

With the current price `99` and opening price `100` this will give `-1.00%`.

That is however not what you asked for. Your description calls for the result to always be a negative percentage, because you specify that the denominator should take the sign that is opposite to the sign of the numerator. I think this formula implements what you are *asking* for:

`=iferror( (C2 - D2) / (C2 * sign(D2 - C2) * 100) )`

With the current price `101` and opening price `100` this will give `-0.01%`.

With the current price `99` and opening price `100` this will also give `-0.01%`.

Alternatively, taking your description *literally*, we get:

`=iferror( C2 - (D2 / C2) * sign(D2 - C2) * 100 )`

...which gives `20000.99%` and `-201.01%` with the above inputs.